# INNER JOIN MYSQL por fecha ignorando los segundos

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, date, join

Tengo tres tablas que guardan un registro aproximadamente cada minuto, pero con delays diferentes en cada tabla, lo que hace que todas tengan registros casi cada minuto pero en segundos diferentes.

Estoy tratando de cruzar  las tres tablas con un inner joint para que me junte la información de aquellos registros que hayan sido guardados en el mismo minuto, ignorando el segundo en el que fuera guardado.

De momento lo he intentado con la siguiente Query:

```
select * from tabla1
INNER JOIN tabla2 ON tabla2.fecha = tabla1.fecha
INNER JOIN tabla3 on tabla3.fecha = tabla1.fecha
GROUP BY tabla1.fecha
ORDER BY tabla1.fecha ASC
```

Pero claro, esto solo me cruza los registros que coinciden en hora minuto y segundo , que son muy pocos.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo para que el join ignore los segundos del campo fecha (campo tipo timestamp)?

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto, básicamente formateamos las fechas para que quitar los segundos y así no los compara.

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tabla1
INNER JOIN tabla2 ON
    DATE_FORMAT(tabla2.fecha, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%i") = DATE_FORMAT(tabla1.fecha, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%i")
INNER JOIN tabla3 ON
    DATE_FORMAT(tabla3.fecha, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%i") = DATE_FORMAT(tabla1.fecha, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%i")
GROUP BY
    tabla1.fecha
ORDER BY
    tabla1.fecha ASC
```

Comment: No puedo saber si funciona, la Query se queda cargando y no llega a ejecutar. Supongo que hay tantos registros a los que convertirles la fecha que se convierte en una query super pesada. Se te ocurre algun metodo mas ligero para hacerlo?

Comment: Pruebalo poniendo un `LIMIT 30` al final, a ver si tarda menos y al menos compruebas que funciona. Por otro lado no, ahoramismo no se me ocurre nada mas ligero... el problema es que siempre tendras mogollon de lineas... y si quieres quitar los segundos, estas obligado a formatear las fechas...

Comment: Me pasa lo mismo aun que le ponga un limit 1

Comment: yo lo he probado con 3 lineas y me va bien

Comment: Prueba a crear un índice: `ALTER TABLE tablax ADD INDEX(fecha);`

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez un `-INTERVAL` resulte algo más ligero que un `DATE_FORMAT()`:

```
SELECT * from tabla1
  JOIN tabla2 ON tabla2.fecha-INTERVAL SECOND(tabla2.fecha) SECOND 
    = tabla1.fecha-INTERVAL SECOND(tabla1.fecha) SECOND
  JOIN tabla3 on tabla3.fecha-INTERVAL SECOND(tabla3.fecha) SECOND
    = tabla1.fecha-INTERVAL SECOND(tabla1.fecha) SECOND
  ORDER BY tabla1.fecha;
```

Y los índices puede que agilicen aún más la consulta:

```
ALTER TABLE tabla1 ADD INDEX(fecha);
ALTER TABLE tabla2 ADD INDEX(fecha);
ALTER TABLE tabla3 ADD INDEX(fecha);
```

He prescindido del `GROUP BY` porque no calculas ningún total sobre los agrupamientos.